# Model / DAO in Android

Tags: java, android

I would like to have a model (or similar) which i want to save and fetch data from. For example; I run an asynctask, and in `onPostExecute` i want to save the return value to the model, which i would be able to make use of in my other classes (once the asynctask is complete ofcourse).

Hopefully you understand what im after here, otherwise ill elaborate.

Thanks!

Comment: @Christine Are you refering to an SQLite db? I have only used sharedPreferences so far. But i suppose a db is better in this case?

Comment: Do you have any programming experience?

Comment: @Christine Yes, ive been coding for a couple of years, but mostly asp.net + c#, why?

Comment: Because if you want to store data, it's common practice to use a database of some kind. On Android, you can use sqlite, like via OrmLite.

Comment: @Christine The data is already beeing saved in an sql database through a webserver which im posting to. But i still think the SQLite solution sounds viable when creating a model class. Thanks